# Куда пропала адаптивность?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть всего 6 букв на примере адаптивность (маленькие экраны) отсутствует: https://zemil.ru/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD/
также есть исходники, однако, адаптивность присутствует:
https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedOpeningType/
Думаю, что конфликт какой-то в стилях, однако, не могу решить проблему. Помогите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под адаптивностью имеется ввиду, что буквы перестраиваются друг под друга, то в референсе есть медиа квери, у вас в примере их нет. То есть нужно под разные разрешения менять ширину .ot-letter-left

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1190px)
{
    .ot-letter-left { width: calc(100% / 5); }
}
```

и так под каждую ширину экрана на которой требуется перестроение.

Comment: но у меня ведь подключен component.css, где заданы стили для разрешений. Или они не работают?если так скажите, почему они могут не работать??

Comment: У вас там много всего подключено, долго разбираться, но в референсе за перестроения отвечает - https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedOpeningType/css/component.css

Однако сомневаюсь, что эти перестроения будут актуальны в вашем случае.

У вас компонентс.цсс совсем другой подключен из того что смог увидеть.